# R Type of Join that repeats Rows

Tags: r, join, datatables

I have two tables: one has the details of all classes given in a school and the other table has the teachers details (codenr of the teacher, fullname, classes that teaches and code of the classes). Both columns have in common the name of the class and also the code of this class. So, I want to join the codenr of the teacher to the classes that he teaches in the table classes but the problem is that some classes are given by more than one teacher so, the table classes would have to repete the rows in this case. Any idea what type of join I can use? I tried with a fulljoin and it doens't do what I was expecting.
[Table Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtttc.png)
[Table Teacher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfagc.png)

Comment: Try with `dplyr::left_join()`

Comment: Thank you! It worked

Comment: Glad to hear it! If it helped you, you can accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `left_join()` from `dplyr`